# script not running on Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome

The following code works on Firefox but not on Chrome- script not running at all, not even the ALERT.

Why is that?

Script should delete row from DB and hide ARTICLE from the screen.

HTML

```
<article class="row" id="410">
    <a href='#' class="btn btn-default btn-xs left delButton" type="comment" delID="410" >DELETE</a>
</article>

<article class="row" id="411">
    <a href='#' class="btn btn-default btn-xs left delButton" type="comment" delID="411" >DELETE</a>
</article>
```

JS

```
$(function() {

    $(document).on('click','.delButton',function() {
//  $(".delButton").click(function(){

        var element = $(this);

        var delID = element.attr("delID");
        var type = element.attr("type");

        var info = 'delID=' + delID + '&type=' +  type;
        alert (info);

        var check = confirm('DELETE?');
        if(check){

             $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "ajax/delete_element.php",
               data: info,
               success: function(data){
                    if (data)
                        $("#"+delID).animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
               }
             });     
         }

        return false;

    });

});
```

Comment: Does the console display any JavaScript errors when you open the page?

Comment: No, but I'm not sure I'm looking on the right place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It does run on chrome...

```js
$(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.delButton', function() {
    //  $(".delButton").click(function(){

    var element = $(this);

    var delID = element.attr("delID");
    var type = element.attr("type");

    var info = 'delID=' + delID + '&type=' + type;
    alert(info);

    var check = confirm('DELETE?');
    if (check) {

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax/delete_element.php",
        data: info,
        success: function(data) {
          if (data)
            $("#" + delID).animate({
              opacity: "hide"
            }, "slow");
        }
      });
    }

    return false;

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="row" id="410">
  <a href='#' class="btn btn-default btn-xs left delButton" type="comment" delID="410">DELETE</a>
</article>

<article class="row" id="411">
  <a href='#' class="btn btn-default btn-xs left delButton" type="comment" delID="411">DELETE</a>
</article>
```